# Create element and append a second element to it before appending to document

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm trying to create an element, and then append another element to the element before passing it to the document. I'm not sure why my code won't work, been testing out different methods.

```js
var count = 0;
 function addElement() {

  count++;

  // Create plan element
  var newElement = document.createElement("li");
  newElement.classList.add("collection-item");

  var main = document.createElement("div");
  var side = document.createElement("a");
  side.classList.add("secondary-content");
  main.appendChild(side);
  newElement.appendChild(main);

  // append element to plan layout
  planDesign.appendChild(newElement);

  // get values
  var exercise = newExcersise.value;
  var set = newSet.value;
  var rep = newRep.value;
  main.innerHTML = "<span>" + count + ".</span>" + exercise;
  side.innerHTML = "<span>Sets: </span>" + set + " <span>Reps: </span>" + rep;
 }
```

I need to get the created "a" element to be inserted into the "div".

[image]

Comment: `main.innerHTML =` this replaces the innerHTML of `main` ... including the `side` element

Answer (score 5):

You are using two different techniques to accomplish the same thing and it's causing you to overwrite your `main` element's content when you say:

```
main.innerHTML = "<span>" + count + ".</span>" + exercise;
```

after successfully appending the `side` element into `main`.

Be consistent when you can. You are using `document.createElement()`, `element.innerHTML` and `element.appendChild()` - different ways of doing the same thing.

If you change the code so that you use the DOM API for creating new nodes (as opposed to creating HTML out of concatenated strings), you will be able to better control the configuration of your elements and where they go.

```
var spn = document.createElement("span");
spn.textContent = count + ".";
main.appendChild(spn);

var text = document.createTextNode(exercise);
main.appendChild(text);
```

Comment: *createElement* and *appendChild* are quite different things.

Comment: @RobG createElement() allows for appendChild(), so it is part of the process for injecting new nodes, as is .innerHTML.

Comment: Sorry, I was commenting on "*You are using document.createElement(), element.innerHTML and element.appendChild() - three different ways of doing the same thing*", but it's really 2 (as you say earlier).